# jQuery accordion - link to open certain div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I am having a nightmare trying to get this working (and have looked at other posts but am still having an issue).

Basically I have a link like this:

```
/test.php#bob
```

on test.php I have this:

```
<div class="accordion">
 <h2>Customer care</h2>
 <div>
  <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
 </div>
 <h2 id="bob">Strong leadership from start to finish</h2>
 <div>
  <p>fffffffffff</p>
 </div>
 <h2>Certainty of delivery, no matter how complex or difficult</h2>
 <div>
  <p>dddddddddd</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

And in jQuery I have this:

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
 autoHeight: false,
 collapsible: true,
 navigation: true,
 active: 'none'
});
```

But I still cant get the #bob panel to open via the link.

Any ideas? Im pulling my hair out.

A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
 autoHeight: false,
 collapsible: true,
 navigation: true,
 active: 'none'
});
if(location.hash) $(location.hash).click();
```

This would perform a `click` on the `<h2>` (by using the hash, which includes the `#` as an [`#id` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)), invoking the standard accordion behavior.