# Programatically opening nested jquery accordion sections

Tags: jquery, nested, accordion

I'm coding a jQuery accordion with text that contains cross-references, so that a link from text in one section needs to open another. Simple enough so far using $(location.hash).click(); as indicated at [jQuery accordion - link to open certain div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022775/jquery-accordion-link-to-open-certain-div)

However the sections I need to open are nested within another accordion:

```
Level 1 heading 1
      Level 2 heading 1
      Level 2 heading 2
      Level 2 heading 3
Level 1 heading 2
      Level 2 heading 1
      Level 2 heading 2
      Level 2 heading 3
... etc
```

How can I make a click to open one of the Level 2 sections open its containing Level 1 accordion section as well?